# Failed to execute send on XMLHttpRequest - error while publishing

Tags: publishing

I am getting the following browser error when I try to publish the site:

```
An error occurred while communicating with the Sitecore server:

Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':
Failed to load 'http://[sitename]/sitecore/shell/Applications/Publish.aspx'.
```

I am using Sitecore 8.1 Update 3.

Comment: did you check your logs files ?

Comment: What is the result, if you try to open the address `http://[sitename]/sitecore/shell/Applications/Publish.aspx` in your browser? Normally you should see the publish dialog window in full screen mode.... please tell us the stacktrace message on your screen or in your logfiles

Comment: still publish is going on

Comment: Is this an out of the box implementation or do you have any addons like Fortis or Unicorn. I had a similar issue the other day.

Comment: I've seen this error when the CM server goes down during publish. Check for an application restart. Also is Mongo running? I've seen Sitecore take ages to respond when mongo is expected to be running but not turned on.

EDIT: If the publish is still running then the website hasn't restarted lol - missed that comment lol